# how to selectively silence rsync

Tags: rsync, debugging

When rsyncing a folder with a million files,

a million lines are output to stduot/stderr, containing
the file names.

(I'm using Travis CI, and this trips it up because their log files can be max 4MB)

How can I tell rsync to not "tell me the file names it's processing"

I still want to hear about hiccups/errors, I just don't want a listing of the files it transferred.

My command is:

```
sudo rsync -avh --no-specials --exclude="foo/" src/ dst/
```

Answer (score 3):

To make rsync less verbose, don't use the `-v` switch, whose entire purpose it to give verbose output including a list of all files transfered.

I would suggest using `rsync --stats -ah [...]` based on your example command.

Answer (score 3):

Besides removing `-v`, when you still need to see some files only but not all you can use grep, for example:

`rsync -avh src/ dst/ | grep file_i_want_to_see*.txt`

or

`rsync -avh src/ dst/ | grep -v string_i_want_to_hide`

note `-v` in the last grep.

Comment: Didnt work; I think because pipe and grep arent applied until after the entire transfer is done. With millions of files, this could be an hour

Comment: For the record, the pipe and grep are applied as soon as the process generates any output